# Parse YAML file with SnakeYaml using custom classes

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to load YAML file content into custom objects I've defined in Java, but no matter which modification I'm doing, I still gets parsing error.

The project configure with Maven.

This is the YAML file content:

```
tables:
- cid: 10
  sopClass: default
  codeMeanings:
    - codeMeaning: Alpha-adrenergic blocking agent
      configurations:
      - type: 0
        Code Meaning: Alpha-adrenergic blocking agent
        Code Value: C-80131
        Coding Scheme Designator: SRT
      - type: 1
        Code Meaning: Alpha-adrenergic blocking agent
        Code Value: '67440007'
        Coding Scheme Designator: SCT
```

The followings are the classes:

CidTable.java:

```
import java.util.List;
public class CidTable {
    private List<CodingSchemeTable> tables;
}
```

CodingSchemeTable.java:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CodingSchemeTable {
    private String cid;
    private String sopClass;
    private List<CodeMeanings> codeMeaning;
}
```

CodeMeanings.java:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CodeMeanings {
    private String codeMeanings;
    private List<Configurations> configurations;
}
```

Configurations.java:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Configurations {
    private List<BasicCodeSequenceMacro> codeSequenceMacros;
}
```

BasicCodeSequenceMacro.java:

```
public class BasicCodeSequenceMacro {
    private int type;
    private final String codeValue;
    private final String codingSchemeDesignator;
    private final String codeMeaning;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot create property=tables for JavaBean=com.test.common.CidTable@7d3d101b
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    tables:
    ^
Unable to find property 'tables' on class: com.test.common.CidTable
 in 'reader', line 2, column 1:
    - cid: 10
    ^
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, if there is another way to parse YAML in Java, please tall. I know that there is a library in cpp, which called `yaml-cpp` and it is great!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for your fields? Or is everything literally as posted?

Comment: `tables` must be either public or have a setter. Same for other fields.